# Localization of Workflow Activity qualified names

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

We use tracking and persistence services of wf, and display current state of workflow on the asp.net page.

Now in the process of localization of our application, we are able to localize all elements on the page except the activity names of workflow. These activity names are given while creating a workflow in VS 2008.

How do i achieve it, any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Activity names are akin to variable names and property names.  These are identifiers which are not normally for user consumption but are used by code in order to find things.  Hence localizing an activity name would be bit like localizing a variable name.

Perhaps there is a way to use the description property of the Activities instead which is designed purely for a humans use (although not necessarily for a users use).  The would require that all the descriptiongs get assigned localised strings during workflow initialisation which might be a bit tricky.  Specifically there would be a need to hold the resource IDs somewhere.  Hmm...